# command for only one user in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Wanted to make a command only for one user, in this case me, i tried this:

```
if (message.author.id !== '655427571831406634') return message.channel.send("Only the owner of the bot can use this command")
```

also tried with an if else but doesn't work neither, any idea?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code. Are you certain you copied the correct ID?

Comment: i'm 100% sure is my id, in fact i'm also confused why it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show the surrounding code?

Comment: at the end i found an other way to do it, i simply made a role for myself and made it check the role instead of the id

Comment: There's still an error with how you checked for your own user id, I think it's best for everyone if you find out what went wrong